# Can I use "at risk" like adverbs?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

1. I climbed the cliff at risk.
2. I walked on the rope at risk.

Are they all possible?

Comment: I believe the phrase you're thinking of is "at *one's own* risk," which is often used to refer to a person doing something which is legal but hazardous or inadvisable. (For example, a sign might say, "No Lifeguard Present - Swim at Your Own Risk.") So, you might say, "I climbed the cliff **at my own risk**," but using just "at risk" in the same context is not idiomatic.

Comment: Both your sentences would be understood to mean that the cliff or the rope was at risk, not you.

Comment: I think you could use that as a modifying phrase if it were in quotes, with a previously established (within the document) sense. It would be sort of indeterminate between adjective and adverb.

Comment: What @QuackE.Duck said. Normally you'd only ***be*** "at risk" - often, "**of** [some danger]". Or *something* might be "at risk" - often, in danger of being lost / forfeited. It's not a general-purpose adverbial.

Comment: "at risk" is a state or condition, not a manner. Like "in danger".  When you are climbing a cliff you are "in danger" but you do not "climb the cliff in danger".